# Simultaneous uploads for files in an folder in Ruby on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, ftp, automation

Ive seen similar questions asked before but none that are as basic as mine.  I know that it is possible to do using `Net::FTP` and threads.  My question is how do you create a thread and pass  it a file to upload.  Im still very new to the concept of threads.

Answer (score 1):

For OSX you could also look into [Automator](http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/index.html) with [Upload to FTP](http://editkid.com/upload_to_ftp/).

However with Ruby something like this could be used as a starting point:

```
def ftp_send_file(file)
  Net::FTP.open("hostname") do |ftp|
    ftp.login("user", "password")
    ...
    ftp.putbinaryfile(file)
  end
end

8.times { |i|
  puts "Starting upload no. #{i}..."

  # Launch a new thread for file upload
  Thread.new { ftp_send_file("the_big_file_#{i}") }
}

# Main thread waits for all upload threads to finish
(Thread.list - [Thread.current]).each(&:join)
```

As you can see it's really not that complicated to start a thread. Just read the [`Thread` docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html). Many more examples in there.

Comment: and would I be correct in assuming that all 8 of the generated threads would be uploading at the same time?

Comment: Yes. That would be the idea. Each upload task is launched into its own thread with `Thread.new`.

Comment: @Myke - added a bit more code and comments to make it clearer.

Comment: @Myke - remember to approve the answer if it helped you

Comment: Sure. You can handle errors in many different ways. Depends on how it fails. Maybe you want to put some [exception handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm) around the FTP section, and then put that inside a loop that keeps retrying if there is an exception of some sort.